# Entity Framework Code First and SQL Azure Connections

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

Where can I find a sample of managing connection retries using SQL Azure and EF 4.1 Code First DbContext? I have found plenty of information on what I should be doing and why, here are some examples:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/05/11/10011247.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabriccat/archive/2010/10/28/best-practices-for-handling-transient-conditions-in-sql-azure-client-applications.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabriccat/archive/2010/12/11/sql-azure-and-entity-framework-connection-fault-handling.aspx
- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1541.aspx

The trouble with these it they all refer to ObjectContext and I can't figure out how to make similar code work for my DbContext without upsetting EF.

Comment: I've created a library which allows you to configure Entity Framework to retry using the Fault Handling block without needing to change every database call - generally you will only need to change your config file and possibly one or two lines of code. This allows you to use it for Entity Framework or Linq To Sql. https://github.com/robdmoore/ReliableDbProvider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upcoming Entity Framework 6 release now includes built in support for connection resiliency, see here for more details:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/08/21/ef6-release-candidate-available.aspx
https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Connection%20Resiliency%20Spec

Answer (score 3):

I am not that familliar with Code-first approach, but I do know you can instantiate the DbContext with a SQL Connection in the [constructor](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-2-connections-and-models.aspx), you could use [Microsoft's Customer Advisory Reliable SQL Connection implementation.](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Reliable-Retry-Aware-BCP-a5ae8e40/sourcecode?fileId=22213&pathId=579782351) This connection has a Retry Policy that handles all the required retry logic you need.

Another option you can do, your implementation of the DbContext can implement the retry logic on each call. again, check out the CAT team's implementation on how to best do that.

Comment: On a side note, you can have a look at their SQL Connection Factory implementation as well, as you'll see in the link to MSDN blog, you can specify the connection factory as well, which is an even better pattern if you don't want to manage your own connections.